# Test-Netconnection Function wrong output

Tags: powershell

I have written a very simple function to test open ports on a server before I install a SQL Server,
In most cases (when the ports are open) the function works just fine returning an empty string, but there are 2 servers I'm getting a wrong otuput (the ports as said are open).
The function:

```
Function CheckPorts
{
param(
    [string]$computerName
)
if($ports = 3389, 445, 5985, 5986, 135 | foreach{Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 
$computerName -Port $_ | where{$_.tcptestsucceeded -eq $false} })
{
    $message = "Port(s): "    
    foreach($port in $ports)
    {
        $message += "$($port.RemotePort), "
    }
    return $message += ": are closed."
}
    return [string]::Empty
}
```

when I call the function:

```
$checkPortsOutput = CheckPorts -computerName $sqlInstance
    if($checkPortsOutput)
        {
            $table.result = "Error"
            $table.definition = "SQL Server Installation: 
            $ServerName, some ports needed for the          
            installation are closed."
            $table.errors = $checkPortsOutput
            throw $table
         }
```

..I'll get an error (my hashtable) like this:

```
{
    "definition": "SQL Server Installation: SQL01-SQL-S007, some 
     ports needed for the installation are closed.",
        "errors": "Port(s): 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, : are closed.",            
     "result": "Error"
    }
```

Comment: What stands out to me is that it says port 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ... are closed. Looks like the command does not run correctly against the SQL server. What happens when you run the Test-NetConnection command manually against SQL01-SQL-S007?

Comment: running the command manually I get a proper answer:
    Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $sqlinstance -Port 5986 

ComputerName     : XX-SQL-P007.dom.net
RemoteAddress    : xx.xx.xxx.125
RemotePort       : 5986
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet0
SourceAddress    : xx.xx.xx.85
TcpTestSucceeded : True

Comment: and I expect an empty string, since all the ports are open.

Comment: Change `3389, 445, 5985, 5986, 135 | foreach{` to `3389, 445, 5985, 5986, 135 | Where-Object {`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen hm, I don't get it... can you please place what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *name resolution* of a given computer name fails (i.e. if the computer name isn't known and no IP address can therefore be determined for it in order to initiate a connection), the `.RemotePort` property of the output objects emitted by [`Test-NetConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection) is `0`.

Note that this condition is accompanied by a *warning* to that effect: `WARNING: Name resolution of <computer-name> failed.`

Therefore, you can rewrite your `CheckPorts` function as follows (`Write-Error` is used to signal the name-resolution failure; adapt as needed):

```bash
Function CheckPorts {
  param(
    [string] $computerName
  )
  if ($closedPorts = 3389, 1, 445, 5985, 5986, 135 | 
       ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject] @{ Port = $_ } } |
       Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $computerName | 
       Where-Object { -not $_.TcpTestSucceeded }
  ) {
    # The .RemotePort property containing 0 implies that name resolution failed.
    if ($closedPorts[0].RemotePort -eq 0) {
      Write-Error "Name resolution of computer '$computername' failed."
    } else {
      "Port(s): $($closedPorts.RemotePort -join ', ') are closed."    
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I've restructured the pipeline with the `Test-NetConnection` call to a flat (non-nested one), so that a *single* call to the latter is sufficient, binding the `-Port` parameter *via the pipeline*, with (custom) objects that have a `.Port` property.

Comment: great, thanks. How did you find out, that .RemotePort property of the output objects  is 0 if the name resolution failes? I didn't find anything about it in the help?

Comment: @Purclot, it was just trial and error. You could argue it's therefore not future-proof to rely on it, but the only other option I can think of is to capture and analyze the text of the warnings, which isn't great either.